# With or without a "be" when a verb in past participle form qualitys a subject

Tags: grammaticality

[Chinese new subway cars start operation in U.S. Boston](http://www.xinhuanet.com/english/2019-08/15/c_138309535.htm)

> New subway cars **built** by a Chinese company for Boston residents
>   started their first run in the U.S. city of Boston on Wednesday.

If I make a sentence which add a "was" between "cars" and "built",

> New subway cars **was built** by a Chinese company ...

Is that grammatical correct? If that is correct, then what's different between with and without the "be"?

Answer (score -1):

To answer your question;  the tense is wrong and we will need a "determiner" in this standalone use.

**New subway cars was built by a Chinese company** it should be **The New subway cars were built by a Chinese company**.

However, the original sentence is a mess **New subway cars built by a Chinese company for Boston residents started their first run in the U.S. city of Boston on Wednesday.**

Boston is **referred to twice**, "For Boston residents" is not correct unless the company who place the order is called **Boston Residents Inc** or similar. The sentence order also does not seem correct what is important in this sentence? Chinese Company, Wednesday, Boston? It is also a **caption** in a newspaper so it should be **short and to the point**.

**Boston, USA, (Wednesday); Residents use Chinese built subway cars, for the first time**

**New**, not needed because for the first time denote it's a new experience.

**Resident use** subway cars they do not purchase them.

**Note** Subjects in A Photo are normally referred to left to right and to name two subjects and not name the third is extremely rude. It is possible to highlight individuals and use the term "seen among others" or something similar, but to totally ignore them. Ugh!!!